# Android send message from my android application to mobile MSISDN

Tags: android, sms

Can some one please guide me how to send sms from an android application to a mobile phone. Any useful links will be of great use to me. I have a edittext where i enter a mobile number. Then i need to send a message to that specified number. Please guide me in this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can try this tutorial

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

after that take a look at this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur response. I need to know how to send message from android application to my number. I need to send a message from my applicationto my sim number(MSISDN) Number.

Comment: Hey, I have a small doubt.. Can some1 please guide me how to get my MOBILE MSISDN Number. Is there any sample application for fetching/ displaying the MSISDN number.

Comment: first actually what do you want above given links are giving full help to send a sms to any mobile phone 
is it not that what you were expecting